# php + html basic formatting

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting query results, but I'm getting syntax errors, such as

> syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on
>   line 32.

If anyone can point out the syntax error I'd be grateful. I've been studying references but am still very new to PHP coding.

```
<?php 
   $now = new \DateTime('now');
   $month1 = $now->format('m');
   $day1= $now->format('j');
    $month = strval($month1);
    $day = strval($day1);
echo $day . $month;

$args  = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    array(
        'key'     => 'month',
        'value'   => '$month',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'day',
        'value'   => '$day',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
         <?php $id  = $post->ID; $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'full'); ?>
                       <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php echo $thumb; ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?> (Today)
            </a>
                </li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: you are already in php 'context', so the `<?php` straight after the while is unnecessary and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to click on that will talk about concatenating your php text.  I encourage you to concatenate where possible instead of constantly breaking in and out of php.

[PHP Concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

When you start a php script by using the php tag, everything inside the php tag are instructions that are executed on the php server.  Once the intructions are executed then the result of the code will output to the browser.

```
<?php

$a = 'Hello';
$b = 'world!';

echo $a . ' ' . $b;  //Will output "Hello world!"

?>
```

In the example above the php tag has been closed. `?>`.  Everything after that will be outputted directly to the browser.

```
<?php

$a = 'Hello';
$b = 'world!';

echo $a . ' ' . $b;  //Will output "Hello world!"

?>

<div>
This html will be directly outputted to the browser.
</div>
```

Now we may need to add some more php.  We can combine the example above by concatenating the div so it is executed by the server and outputted to the browser.

```
<?php

$a = 'Hello';
$b = 'world!';

echo $a . ' ' . $b;  //Will output "Hello world!"

echo
'<div>
This will be outputted to the browser as a result of the execution of the php by the server. 
Lets write "' . $a . ' ' . $b . '" again.
</div>';

?>
```

Notice that I never had to break in and out of php using the `<?php` or `?>` tags.

Also I would look into getting a good code editor.  I use Atom.  You can configure a php linter that will show you were you are making errors as you code.  It also has some inteltype features that will auto-populate variable and function names as you type.  Here is a link for atom.  You will have to add on the linter plugin after your install.  You should be able to find stuff on Stack Overflow and google to help you with that.  Once you get it set up you will like it alot.

[Atom](https://atom.io/)

As far as your code goes, I rewrote it like I showed in the above example.  Here you go.

```
<?php

$now = new \DateTime('now');
$month1 = $now->format('m');
$day1= $now->format('j');
$month = strval($month1);
$day = strval($day1);

echo $day . $month;

$args  = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    array(
        'key'     => 'month',
        'value'   => '$month',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'day',
        'value'   => '$day',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts()) {
echo
'<ul>';

  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

    $id = $post->ID; $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'full');
    echo 
    '<li>' .
      '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . $thumb . the_title() . (Today) . '</a>' .
    '</li>';

  endwhile;

echo
'</ul>';

}

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Notice that I never broke in and out of PHP.

Hopefully this will help you out a little bit going forward.

Comment: Thank you! I love this approach, of just staying in php. So much easier than deeking in and out.

Thank you so much for the time you spent to walk through it all, too. You cleared up all the confusion that was pouring into my head from youtube videos and googled (bad) examples.

I got Atom, thank you for taking the time as well to recommend that.

I feel like I really learned from you. I appreciate it!

Comment: Hey no problem! It's ok to break in and out of php, There is just no need to do it constantly.  Sometime it's easier to write a big block of html and put a few sections of php or vise versa.  I just try not to do it often.  And don't forget to set up the linter on Atom you will like it alot.